# Surround Number to interpret as Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, oledb, powerquery

I have a CSV files and one of the fields named `period` stores number. Now within SSRS, I need to make use of a multi-value parameter, due to the workings of SSRS to use this with a CSV I need to do `Join(Parameters!Period.Value, ",")`.

This issue with this is then my data set has the following query:

```
="SELECT WarehouseZone, RevenueStream,ClientID,CONVERT(varchar(10),Period) FROM BudgetCSV.csv 
WHERE WarehouseZone IN ('" & Join(Parameters!Warehouse.Value,"', '") & "') 
AND (RevenueStream IN ('" & Join(Parameters!AnalysisCode.Value,"', '") & "'))
AND (ClientID IN ('" & Join(Parameters!Customer.Value,"', '") & "'))
AND (CONVERT(varchar(10),Period) IN  ('"& Join(Parameters!Period.Value, "','") & "'))"
```

This code works fine for the zone, stream and client, I get a data type mismatch of period.

Is there any way using Powerquery to have the csv think that `period` is text. I have seen somewhere that by making the column say `="1"` it would interpret that as text instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK - Using this method only works on an individual level, luckily there is a better solution**

So I mentioned in an earlier post that I could get around using the Join by creating a single parameter for each period, but this was causing an issue where if I selected 10, 1 would also be return because, strings.

This was due to me using the following code on each of these parameters

```
=iif(Join(Parameters!Period.Value,",").ToLowerInvariant().Contains("10"), "10",-999)
```

Simple changing that code to the following

```
=iif(Join(Parameters!Period.Value,",") = 1, 1,-999)
```

So the issue is solved, but any input on how I could get a more dynamic solution working would be great as there may be times in the future when I need to use a longer list of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [Text.From](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-from) or [Number.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-totext) to convert a number value to text.

```
Text.From(Period)
```

or

```
Number.ToText(Period)
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work as when I export it to CSV it still considers the column to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding as another answer for posterity to see my mistakes.

There is in fact a much easier way to achieve this. [image]

By adding the above filter onto the dataset you can achieve this without the need for any SQL or any extra parameters. This is probably obvious to anyone who has been working with SSRS for any length of time, but I'm rather new to it myself.